# Android - Images on Canvas

Tags: java, android, image-manipulation, android-canvas

What is the best way of creating a layer for holding images below a transparent canvas layer so that I can manipulate the images with gesture events.

Right now I have a canvas on which I can draw and scribble, and I need a container for images and label objects that I can move around and resize as needed below the canvas. Is this possible? what or where is the best place to get some solid information on accomplishing this. Project is being done using Java.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think implementing this with native Views may not be the best approach. I'd consider implementing that with OpenGL using a TextureView(1) and render the transformed images there using OpenGL textures.

(1) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html